# Unable to set/edit cookies in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I realised today, that I'm no longer able to edit or create new cookies in Chrome. It works in Firefox and Safari as of now.

I go to **Developer Tools > Applications > Cookies** and try to change their values. The line turns red and if I click out, it resets to what it was.

Do I have to deactivate something somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yep, solved by:

1. search in chrome settings for flags by entering in the url field `chrome://flags`
2. search `Partitioned cookies` and set it to `enable`
3. Restart chrome (might need to refresh the page after the restart)

Answer (score 1):

From 2024: enable `Allow third-party cookies`